# monero-win-x64-v0.10.2.1 CLI questions

Tags: monerod

Is this version no longer "colorized"? It's all black and white. Except when I type "status", then the result is in green. Previous versions had blue, green and occasional red messages...just wondering if everything is working correctly with this newest version.

Also, getting a bunch of "RATE LIMIT NOT IMPLEMENTED HERE YET download at unlimited speed?"  What does that mean and what do I do about it?

Comment: you can just ignore those warnings don't worry about it. i'll let someone with more understanding answer specifically why this happens in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version switched to EasyLogger which uses ANSI escape sequences to set colors on the window. Windows 10 has built-in support for these command codes, but on earlier versions you'll need some other terminal program to render them. For some alternatives: https://superuser.com/questions/413073/windows-console-with-ansi-colors-handling/1050078

Comment: Thank you, hyc. I just started using ConEmu per your link and I got it working in all it's colored glory. It also allows other improved aspects over the regular cmd.exe (Windows 7) that I've already noticed. Cool.

Comment: I'm using the latest Windows 10, and the ANSI escape codes are not rendering as colors; they're coming out as raw text. -- Anything special I need to do?